# Behind the abstraction, how does the third parameter (or next(), typically) work behind the abstraction layer in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As for a simple example, in this two sample code here, how is a next() a parameter and how can
it be executed to automatically go to the next middleware function? How does this work behind the abstraction?

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Time2:', Date.now())
  next()
});
```

This outputs:
Time: (Now's date)
Time2: (Now's date)

This is done from top to bottom.

Comment: _"how is a next() a parameter"_ - you're passing a callback to Express. It calls it back with various parameters, including a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is done from top to bottom.

Not necessarily. What happens is that `app.use()` collects the middlewares in an array. Then when a request comes in, the router goes through that array and can create the respective `next` callback for each middleware so that it will run the remaining handlers. The router also selects the middlewares according to path, method, etc if you have restricted them - which you didn't in your example.

Here's a small demo:

```js
function app(req, res, last) {
  const run = app.middlewares.reduceRight((nextStep, middleware) => {
    const step = (err) => {
      // if (err) …
      middleware(req, res, nextStep);
    };
    return step;
  }, last);
  run();
}
app.middlewares = [];
app.use = function(middleware) {
  app.middlewares.push(middleware);
};

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Time2:', Date.now())
  next()
});

app({}, {}, () => console.log('last'));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help Bergi..

Answer (score 2):

`next` will be a closure that contains a reference to the array of middlewares and the current index (or some equivalent data). So when you call it, it increments the index and calls that middleware's function. Each call to `next()` steps through all the middlewares until it gets to the end.

Comment: Good answer, but needs quite a bit of unpacking for less senior developers

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting to know more about this now.